# Error in Azure BizTalk Services reading XML message from a Service Bus Queue

Tags: azure, azure-servicebus-queues, biztalk-services

Background

1. I created a web service on Azure that will take a transaction, convert it to an XML Message (using a Schema) and pass it onto a Azure Service Bus Queue.
2. I de-serialized the XML object to a string before I move it to the queue due to BizTalk Services inability to de-serialized any XML objects.
3. All configuration on the queue seem fine and the message looks like this:
   `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <QueueTransaction xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" TransactionID="1040" TransactionType="MyAirtimeTest1" Amount="123456" Status="NEW" TransactionDate="1/28/2015 12:00:00 AM" xmlns="http://MMBTService.TransactionSchema" />`
4. I create a BizTalk Service Message Flow with Service Bus Queue Source, Xml One-Way Brodge and One-Way External Service EndPoint(The endpoint are a WCF Web Service)
5. I have two schemas, using a MAP the source XML data to the Web Service Schema.
6. I selected the Request Message Type (Source Schema), only Validate is set as True, I disabled all the Enrich and my MAP in the XMLTransform.

ERROR I RECEIVE

After I deployed everything, gong into Tracking on BizTalk Services, I get the following error: **Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.**

I have gone through this for a few days now and checked every little detail in de-serializing the message to the bridge config, but cannot find the problem.

Any advise or help will really be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

From the problem description it seems to be an UTF encoding issue. The Message that you receive in the Azure Service Bus Queue is in UTF-8 encoding. However the Bridge that you created is expecting the message to be UTF-16 encoding.

To make sure this is issue, you can check the messages received in Azure Queue using the Service Bus Explorer developed by Microsoft Guy S Paolo. You can trying changing the message UTF-8 to UTF-16 to same Queue and check if that works.

Hope it helps.

Thanks